# Which is the smallest known particle that scientists have actually *seen with their eyes*?

Tags: experimental-physics, particle-physics, particle-detectors, microscopy

Which is the smallest particle that has been actually seen by the scientists?  When I say "actually seen", (may be using some ultra advanced microscope or any other man made eye, using any wavelength or phenomena) I really mean it; just like we have seen the  [red blood cells](http://www.wellcome.ac.uk/stellent/groups/corporatesite/@msh_publishing_group/documents/image/wtdv030817.jpg).

[Davidmh's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104523/which-is-the-smallest-known-particle-that-scientists-have-actually-seen-with-th/104526#104526) is pretty much in line with what I am asking

Comment: Note that it is *not* straightforward to define 'seen'. Many particles are smaller than the wavelength of visible light, and can therefore not be 'seen', but one can transform smaller wavelength waves to visible light.... Does this still count as 'seeing' to you?

Comment: @Danu of course since an ultra advanced microscope I mentioned above, might do this, to make it visible.  Some thing which I can say hey, look thats is the particle-x.

Comment: Ok. But then, I don't see how this is fundamentally different from using, say, an electron tunneling microscope (which uses tunneling, not some kind of EM radiation) to 'see' something. If detecting a particle in this way also counts as seeing, then I don't see why the things done at the LHC don't.

Comment: I am not aware of how tunneling works. I understand looking at a "particle" and looking at its "effects" that it shows in some way are two different things. And I am interested in the former not in the later.

Comment: What I'm trying to clarify is that it is not easy to draw a line between the two. In a sense, a particle's interaction with light is also just an effect, and it's a slippery slope.

Comment: Actually seen, to me means that the photon emitted or reflected by the object is the same photon absorbed by the scientist's eye. Therefore any system not working in the visible spectrum regime will fail this test. Any more advanced observation protocol will not be a direct observation but one based on indirect effects.

Comment: @gregsan Right... But OP indicated that this is not what he was asking about, which makes it all more subtle than that.

Comment: Comment to the question (v4): What scientific detectors are included vs excluded in OP's phrase _some ultra-advanced microscope or any other man-made eye?_

Comment: Perception is all about observing the effect of something. What is the difference between a man made eye like a ccd sensor (which you seem to accept) and a photographic plate (which you exclude)? Both of them are sensitive to the effect of photons hitting them, as it is the human eye. I really cannot understand the question :/

Comment: When light scatters off an electron, are you seeing the electron or not? Maybe your definition takes into account the resolving limit?

Comment: Without some clarification on what exactly gpuguy means  by "seeing" a particle, this question isn't answerable as is.

Comment: Contemplate bubble chamber photos : https://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/ the paths/tracks in the chamber are left by the  particles, as they travel through the medium and ionize it. Consider that electrons are point particles and there can be nothing smaller than a point. You might learn something from the parent site too https://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/

Comment: This question is one that seems obvious and clear to the layman, but is very subtle in the mind of an expert. You have said on one hand that Davidmh's answer is what you want, but on the other hand it fails your own "same photon" test because that is the scan of a long exposure photograph. The question could just as well be "opinion based".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Taking your question literally, [you can see a single barium ion](http://www.rug.nl/kvi-cart/research/trimp/trimpnews/news-2013/capture-of-a-single-barium-ion):

> The TRIµP group has achieved capturing a single barium ion in a Paul trap. The images show Coulomb crystals formed by a decreasing number of laser-cooled ions as detected with an EMCCD camera. This forms an important step towards the planned experiments on single radium ions to measure atomic parity violation and build an ultra-stable optical clock.

[image]

They are in traps like this one:

[image: Barium ion trap]

Also, [Warren Nagourney from Washingtong University took a picture of a single Barium atom scattering light from a laser](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fatllama/43155091/):

[image: Single trapped atom, glowing blue]

> **Single trapped atom, glowing blue**
>
> Photo credit: Warren Nagourney at the University of Washington, c. 2000
>
> **What is this?**
>
> Believe it or not, this is a color photograph of a single trapped barium ion held in a radio-frequency Paul trap. Resonant blue and red lasers enter from the left and are focused to the center of the trap, where the single ion is constrained to orbit a region of space about 1 millionth of a meter in size.
>
> **What's the red/blue mess on the sides?**
>
> Low level out-of-focus laser scatter off of metal trap electrodes and accessories (atom ovens, electron filaments, etc.) as seen in this photo.
>
> **How do we know the dot really is an atom?**
>
> When one turns off the red laser, the blue dot vanishes. This is because the scattering process requires both laser colors due to a metastable state in the barium ion. If the blue dot stayed around with the red laser off, we might excuse it as being additional laser scatter off some surface.
>
> **How was the photo taken?**
>
> This is a scanned photo; the camera was a 35mm Nikon (I believe) with a wide open 50mm f/1.8 lens. The exposure time was two minutes. Several shots were taken at different camera positions and this one caught the ion in the very narrow depth of field.
>
> **Is this how you normally "view" the ion?**
>
> No, we use a 50 mm f/1.8 camera lens to image the blue dot onto a photomultiplier tube. We don't require the focus to be so good when using the PMT.
>
> **Where can I see more?**
>
> Lots of CCD images of one and several trapped ions are found on the Monroe group site.

Only two minutes exposure time, so probably in a dark enough room, someone with good sensitivity could actually see it.

Comment: How do you prove it is a SINGLE atom? :D Then electron microscope and everything what is visible in it is also a good answer. Question HERE is HOW small, and if its not a single atom but a molecule this changes answer at least by a factor of 2.

Comment: AsphirDom see the edits (thanks to @user11153 for the bulk of that work). If you had actually followed the links you would have found exactly that information.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty so exactly which phrase answers my question?

Comment: How about the paragraph below "How do we know the dot really is an atom?"? If you're worried that the single dot is actually masking as two atoms, that is so not an issue anymore that ion trappers don't bother making that explicit. The distances between ions in a trap were already well characterized in the early 90s, and the optics are of course perfectly well understood. If there were indeed two atoms, you'd see two dots, as in the first image.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty How simple everything is! AH! :) Ok. Lets assume your arguments are plausible.

Comment: Wow. So is this optical microscopy of single atoms? Pretty close to diffraction limit!

Comment: Can we say that chances are overwhemingly in favor of the scattered light bouncing off the electric field of the ion without coming too close to the ion's matter? And is the size of the electric field that makes it possible for a visible wavelenght to even interact with the ion in the first place, because if it was a neutral atom its detection size would be too small for a visible wavelenght?

Comment: @Ponce under the right conditions, you can see a single photon. Also, stars are way smaller than what you can resolve, and no-one would argue you cannot see them.

Answer (score 8):

Obviously, the smallest particle that scientists have ever seen directly is a photon.

The question is a bit silly because it tries to eliminate any simple device like a photographic plate. But the human eye, its nerves and the visual cortex together are far more complicated.

Comment: I was tempted to say this, but since the typical definition of "see" means to detect photons reflected or emitted from the object in question, you can't really get away with this answer. :-) .  Personally I don't think it counts as "seeing" an atom which just gave off a photon, either.  That's "detection" rather than "recognition."

Comment: Well, the photon is obviously ~seen~ and is therefore a pretty darn small particle that is "observable using only the naked eye" :)

Comment: You definitely do not see photons. First of all, sight is optical detection of photons that have reflected off of the subject; photons do not bounce off one another to the best of my knowledge. Second, if photons hitting your eye counted as you seeing those photons, then a blind person could see sand when it hits them in the eyes. Detection using your eyes does not constitute seeing, unless that is your comprehensive definition of sight. Actually, if you define detection of photons hitting your eyes as sight of those photons and not their origin, then you have never seen a physical object, eve

Comment: When there is so much light that you just see white. Are you seeing something or nothing?

Comment: @JohnP : So you can't see the sun? Or a light bulb? They don't exactly reflect photons. That there's more to seeing than just eyes is true; see the last line of my post.